# Find and Remove Grayscale Effect from Wordpress Gallery

Tags: wordpress, hover, effect

I've been banging my head all day, and still can't find the solution!

URL: http://wmy.2ec.myftpupload.com/gallery/

I want to remove the Grayscale effect from the Gallery thumbnails, I've tried searching for CSS code, PHP code, nothing to my avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll walk you through the diagnostic process for this. Open up DevTools by right clicking on an element you want to debug and choosing **Inspect**.

Click up the DOM tree until you find an element that appears to have the CSS properties you're looking to adjust.

In your case it's relatively straightforward, the `img` tag has a `filter: grayscale(1)` property set:

[image: Screenshot of dev tools]

If you're using a [Child Theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes), you can most likely edit that line of your CSS file, and you're done!

If you're aren't, or you're unsure, you can add CSS in the **Appearance > Customize > Additional CSS** section of your site (or wherever else your theme/plugins allow you to place CSS or "Header Scripts")

You'll need some CSS that's got a [higher specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#:%7E:text=Specificity%20is%20the%20means%20by,different%20sorts%20of%20CSS%20selectors) to override that CSS. You can usually just copy the highlighted selector and add `body` in front of it, or add an ID somewhere that exists. Avoid using `!important` unless you absolutely have to (overriding inline-styles or other baked-in `!importants` that you can't remove).

Adding

```
body .tm-pg_front_gallery .tm-pg_front_gallery-masonry .tm_pg_gallery-item a img {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
    filter: grayscale(0);
}
```

or

```
body .tm-pg_front_gallery .tm-pg_front_gallery-masonry .tm_pg_gallery-item a img,
body .tm-pg_front_gallery .tm-pg_front_gallery-grid .tm_pg_gallery-item a img,
body .tm-pg_front_gallery .tm-pg_front_gallery-justify .tm_pg_gallery-item a img {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
    filter: grayscale(0);
}
```

Should give you the result you're looking for: [image: screenshot of results]

Comment: This worked like a charm, I added the custom CSS code to Simple CSS, many thanks for the fix! 

But, what I find very strange, when I edit the CSS file manually, setting the grayscale to 0, nothing happens. For some reason the edits are ignored, I'm using WinSCP, and Notepad++.